# phpunit does not delete factory created records after catch block

Tags: laravel, exception, phpunit

I'm writing tests in laravel-Framework with PHPUnit Version 9.0 (PHP Version 7.4). I use factories to create database records for each test.

I have to test the failed method of a Job, that throws an exception at the end. The code of this methods looks like this (I'm not able to show you the real code):

```
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
{
    Patient::find($this->user->id)->update([
        'export_status_type' => 'failed',
        'ended_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]);

    \Storage::put('protocols/exports/' . $this->path, $content);

    throw new ExportException('Export failed');
}
```

In my test I bound the method call in a try and catch block. Otherwise it will stop after calling the method, because of the thrown Exception.

The problem is, that it doesn't delete the database records, which the tests creates through factories. Here is my test code:

```
use WithoutMiddleware;
use DatabaseTransactions;


/** @test */
public function it_fails_to_export()
{
    //It creates db records through database
    $partner = $this->createPartners();
    $this->createPatients($partner);
    $this->createProtocols($partner);
    
    //Some tests for the created records
    $this->assertCount(3, Patient::all());
    //...
    
    try
    {
        $export_job = new ExportJob;
        //it calls the failed function that updates a database record and throws an exception
        $export_job->failed(new ExportException('failed'));

    }catch (ExportException $exception)
    {

        //The message above always reachs to the catch block, because of the thrown exception. Here it has to make a few assertions
        $this->assertCount(3, Patient::all());

        //After the tests I have to force delete all the used database tables, because phpunit doesn't delete them itself in that case.
        Patient::withTrashed()->forceDelete()
        Partner::withTrashed()->forceDelete();
        Protocol::withTrashed()->forceDelete();
    }
}
```

Is there another way to tell phpunit/laravel that the thrown Exception should be ignored in this case. I dont't need this for every test, but especially for that one. Because with the try and catch block phpunit does not delete the created database records (through factories).

Or is something else missing/wrong?

I hope someone has an idea :)

Comment: The `failed($exception)` parameter is unused, you should drop it from the function, it is superfluous. Not what you've asked for but perhaps it helps if there are more errors.

Comment: Having an exception thrown will not prevent the transaction from rolling back. Does your models have another connection than the default?

Comment: Well, I still don't know where the problem was, but I wanted to check anything today an now it works. I'm sorry for that unnecessary question -.-